# Class not found exception on starting tomcat 6 server from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

I am using tomcat 6 server in eclipse for a spring application.After deploying the latest war in webapps folder of the server, when I am starting the server, it throws class not found exception with the following stack trace.

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.abc.xyz.BootStrapper
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.xyz.BootStrapper
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.xyz.listener.xyzServletContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xyz.listener.xyzServletContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/xyz] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM waffle.apache.MixedAuthenticator stop
INFO: [waffle.apache.MixedAuthenticator] stopped
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8086
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/12  config=null
Sep 15, 2015 11:01:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 609 ms
```

Kindly help me to figure this out.

Thanks,
Poorna.

Comment: May be you can go in Eclipse’s Servers view, right click on the server you are trying to start and choose “Clean". Once done, try restarting the server, hopefully you won't see this error any more

Comment: No,the esception is still there..:(

Comment: Have you imported someone else's project,if yes try removing the servlet.api jar and adding a fresh jar from your env.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720224/severe-error-configuring-application-listener-of-class-org-apache-catalina-depl .This might help.

Comment: what is spring version you are using?

Comment: Hi All,Thanks for your replies..I just uninstalled the tomcat server and re installed it.I t worked fine.