# Hi, I am importing a maven project to eclipse work space and trying to run the program im getting the following error,

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4984)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

First i imported maven project and then i set the targeted runtime to apache tomcat 7 and in preferences i changed thr jre runtime to jdk runtime. next am i missing any steps?

Comment: Please keep your question titles brief and include the description of the problem in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720224/severe-error-configuring-application-listener-of-class-org-apache-catalina-depl)

Comment: If that doesn't help, then there's this http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-error-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect You might missed the dependency:

Try add and check:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

if above not working check this answer also:

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl)